# use of wordnet api to check whether name of a place, person or organisation

Tags: java, api, nlp, wordnet

can word net or any other API tell what a given word is?? i mean whether it is name of a place or person or organization ??
i want to use this API in JAVA using url links of the API.
can anybody please help me in finding any working API or any relevant material regarding this.

i have also used he alchemy api, but it does not solve the above problem.
i have extracted keywords from text using alchemy api. now i want to further analyze whether keyword is name of a place or person.

http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedConcepts
this is the http url i use in my java code to extract keywords.

Answer (score 2):

WordNet is different things to different people, but for me it *exists* to tell you exactly that. Once you have identified the word in the WordNet graph (e.g. "Ferrari"), follow the hypernym link to its parent, "Sports Car". Then to its parent "car".
and it's parent "motor vehicle#1", then "self-propelled vehicle#1", etc., and eventually you reach "artifact#1".

The quick way is to just look which file it is in. I.e. "car" is in "noun.artifact".

If you started with Abraham Lincoln, well, it is in noun.person, so you immediately know it is a person.

If you started with just "lincoln", it could be "person", "location" or "animal":
  http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=1&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=1&o5=1&o9=&o6=1&o3=1&o4=1&s=Lincoln&i=0&h=000#c

But dealing with that is a separate challenge and a separate question :-)

WordNet as a DB for word classification is completely dependent on the word existing in WordNet. E.g. the City Of Lincoln found in England is not there. The Lincoln movie is not there. The Lincoln motor company is not found. If you are dealing mostly with commercial entities, then WordNet is the wrong data source. (I created MLSN to add all these kinds of words, but that project has been stalled for a few years now, and is currently offline, so is no help to you, sorry.)

Sorry, I cannot help with the Java API or Alchemy.